# CXF 2 legged oauth example

Tags: oauth, cxf

is there an example of a 2 legged oauth implementation with cxf ?

the documentation has an implementation for a 3 legged implementation, but not a 2 leg.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For 2 legged implementation you need to use either "password" or "client_credentials" grant.
The first one is for acting on behalf of an end user, and the second one is for acting as a client app itself.

There is an example in their docs right now. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that I ended up using.

```
WebClient client =  WebClient.create(LOGIN_ENDPOINT);
Consumer consumer = new Consumer(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET); //The registered client
ClientAccessToken accessToken = OAuthClientUtils.getAccessToken(client, consumer, new ResourceOwnerGrant(USER_ID, USER_SECRET), false);
```

It implements the "[Resource Ownner Password Credentials Access Grant Type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-10#section-4.1.2)"